# XLST transform - XML to HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml as,

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="htmlConvertor.xsl"?>
<testrun name="TestAll (10)" project="ProjectName" tests="8" started="8" failures="0" errors="0" ignored="0">
  <testsuite name="testall" time="1.1">
    <testsuite name="package_1" time="1.1">
      <testcase name="test_1" classname="class_1" time="0.918"/>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuite>
</testrun>
```

Here i wish to generate a html table with the data from above xml and i have a xsl as below,

**htmlConvertor.xsl**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <h2><center>Junit Results</center></h2>
                    <h3>
                        Project :
                        <xsl:value-of select="testrun/@project"></xsl:value-of>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        Total Tests :
                        <xsl:value-of select="testrun/@tests"></xsl:value-of>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        Fail :
                        <xsl:value-of select="testrun/@failures"></xsl:value-of>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        Errors :
                        <xsl:value-of select="testrun/@errors"></xsl:value-of>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        Ignored :
                        <xsl:value-of select="testrun/@ignored"></xsl:value-of>
                    </h3>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th>
                                <b>Class Name</b>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <b>Method Name</b>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <b>Status</b>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <b>Execution Time</b>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="testrun/testsuite/testsuite/testcase">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@classname" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                                </td>

                                <xsl:variable name="result" select="failure"></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$result"></xsl:value-of> -->
                                    <xsl:when test="$result != '' ">
                                        <td bgcolor="#F51707">
                                            <b>Fail</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <td bgcolor="#07F54B">
                                            <b>Pass</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@time" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have both the xml and xsl files in same local directory. But when i open the xml in firefox 18 and firefox 28 the xlst is not applied and it displays as blank page. And in IE 8 it displays xml contents without any xslt.

**Note:** I tried copy pasting my xml and xsl codes in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) and it works there.

Where am i going wrong here? Any help or suggestions?

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp. Other than that, you will need to use an XSLT Processor to take your `test.xml` input and your `htmlConvertor.xsl` XSLT to produce a HTML file.

Comment: @Roberto that works out. Thank you. But still i wonder when i tried the same xsl and xml about 6 months back in older firefox, it works when xml and xsl are in same directory. Not sure why now it is not been working. May be some cross-site restriction been brought in newer updates of firefox. Any ides?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm fairly new to XSLT myself and I wasn't even aware that what you were trying to do was ever possible.

Comment: Die you load it in a browser using file:// or http:// ? I think file:// won't work anymore in FF

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment at the moment so...

Try saving your XSL document as an XSLT document and changing this line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="htmlConvertor.xsl"?>
```

in your XML document to;

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="htmlConvertor.xslt"?>
```

Comment: Strange. I have just copied your code as it is in your question and ran it using IE9 on my machine and it opens up and renders the page using the XSLT just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're matching on the node `testrun` when you match the root node `/`, then you're using the name again in the body of the template. Replace `testrun` with `.` which means the current or matched node:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="testrun">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2><center>Junit Results</center></h2>
                <h3>
                    Project :
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@project"></xsl:value-of>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                    Total Tests :
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@tests"></xsl:value-of>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                    Fail :
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@failures"></xsl:value-of>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                    Errors :
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@errors"></xsl:value-of>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                    Ignored :
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@ignored"></xsl:value-of>
                </h3>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>
                            <b>Class Name</b>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <b>Method Name</b>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <b>Status</b>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <b>Execution Time</b>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./testsuite/testsuite/testcase">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@classname" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            </td>

                            <xsl:variable name="result" select="failure"></xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$result"></xsl:value-of> -->
                                <xsl:when test="$result != '' ">
                                    <td bgcolor="#F51707">
                                        <b>Fail</b>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <td bgcolor="#07F54B">
                                        <b>Pass</b>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@time" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The xml and xsl works in onlie w3 schools executor. So i guess it is not appropriate to change testrun to ".". Any how i tried your solution of changing testrun to ".' and it DID NOT WORK OUT!!!

Comment: When you say it works, what do you mean? What output are you trying to get? For example, what are you expecting the variable `result` to be? What are the values for the `h3` tags `Projects`, `Total Tests`, etc?

Comment: It works means, i able to view the html table with data from xml. Can you please copy paste the xml and xsl in my question to the link i mentioned in the question, so that you will get clarified.

Comment: I changed to template match select from `/` to `testrun` and left my `.` selectors. It works with firefox.  Within a template `.` refers to the matched node. With my tweak, this is explicitly `testrun`. I think that there may be differences between processors when you match on the root with `/`. In some cases, it may have refered to `testrun`, in which case your template would not produce correct output. But in w3schools it apparently selected something else (not sure what).